Identifying and blocking email spoofer with server tools
In the past 24 hours I received over 60 emails about bounces to random email addresses I did not send a message to, and I also received spam in the same account. The email account is connected to a server I manage.
I have DKIM and SPF keys active.
I want to literally block whoever is spoofing and I can block people with IP addresses, but what standard unix utilities can I use to identify the real origin that is doing the email spoofing?

It is not clear from your question which of the addresses in the messages where spoofed. Quite possibly there is something you can change in your DNS to stop people from "returning" you those messages. Show the headers of such message, and your published SPF and DMARC records.

How did you verify that it is not your email server that sends the emails?

I now configured the server to replace the affected email address with a different one. It wasn't an issue because it was my email.
